# Split a string based on a number given?

Tags: java, string

NOTE: NO NEED TO UPDATE THIS QUESTION ITS FINE. I figured a way to solve it on my own.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static String splitStringUserNumb(String message, int x){
  String result= "";


  //Something I have to do here but not sure how I can approach the problem
  int countToSplit = 0;

  for(int i =0; i < text.length(); i){

    if(countToSplit == SplitStringNum){
         result+= text.substring(i,)
     }



    countToSplit++;
    }



  return result;
}
```

Comment: You'll want a loop, getting substrings of size `x` until the string's length is smaller than `x`.

Comment: I tried but not sure how to do it, this is what I have I will put it up on there

Comment: you should show us your previus code like that we can give you some advices

Comment: Frist of all you should declare `SplitStringNum`. Then you must add a different condition to split your string then reset again your counter

Comment: I can promise you I tried something like that but I'm not really sure how to do it the way you intend to. Can you show me how ?

Comment: @newprogrammer if you found a solution, please just delete the question.

Comment: Or post you answer to the question here.

Comment: @newprogrammer I tried with some answer. But I forgot to give an explanaition. So far I regret to waste my time for doing it.

Comment: @SergeiSirik sure, but OP should restore the question too. Right now we can't see what was being asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
 public static String splitStringUserNumb(String message, int x) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

    int start = 0;
    for(int i = x; i < message.length(); i += x){
      res.append(message, start, i);
      res.append(" ");
      start = i;
    }

    res.append(message, start, message.length());
    return res.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new SplitStringTest().splitStringUserNumb("200211992", 1));
    System.out.println(new SplitStringTest().splitStringUserNumb("200211992", 2));
    System.out.println(new SplitStringTest().splitStringUserNumb("200211992", 3));
    System.out.println(new SplitStringTest().splitStringUserNumb("200211992", 4));
    System.out.println(new SplitStringTest().splitStringUserNumb("", 3));
  }
```

Output:

```
2 0 0 2 1 1 9 9 2
20 02 11 99 2
200 211 992
2002 1199 2
```

Comment: Thanks but I found an easier solution the problem myself. thanks for your effort

Comment: `res.append(message, start, i)` is better, it avoids creating a substring. But note that you'll get an exception if the number does not exactly divide the string length (and you will get an extra space on the end).

Comment: Thanks, updated the code. I tested it, seems like no issues with exception or extra space.

Comment: @SergeiSirik if there's no extra space, get rid of the trim :) that somewhat defeats the advantage of a string builder anyway.

Comment: @SergeiSirik oh, I see why it doesn't. Ok.

Comment: @Andy Turner, updated the code, got rid of `String` `trim()` and `subString()`. Tested - no exception or extra space in the end.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

where;

text is original string,
x is number to split by

```
public static String splitStringUserNumb(String text, int x){
    String result= "";

    for(int i =0; i < text.length() - x; i += x){
        result += text.substring(i,i+x);
    }

    return result;
}
```

if you are wondering why you need to do `text.length() - x` it's because you do not want to split it after the index goes out of bounds